# Would a voltaic cell still work if you replaced both the cathode and anode with a carbon/graphite electrode?

Tags: electrochemistry

for example, in this cell:

Zn(s)|Zn2+(aq)||Ag+(aq)|Ag(s)

if you replace the silver cathode with a carbon electrode, i know it would still transfer electrons, but if you also replaced the Zinc electrode with a carbon one, would it still work?

I saw some examples where inert electrodes were used, and one would be carbon, the other Platinum. This is (what im asking about) the reason why you need separate ones?

[image]

Comment: What net chemical reaction you suppose would be the source of electrical energy ?

Comment: the zinc? but isn't this cell dependent on the fact that electrons need to react, but based on that logic, neither of the electrodes can be changed?

Comment: Is zinc a chemical reaction ? There must be ongoing 2 spatially separated redox half-reactions, one providing electrons, once consuming electrons. Generally, electrodes may, or may not react.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the silver electrode by a carbon one, the cell would still work, as $\ce{Ag+}$ can still be reduced and deposit itself on carbon( that becomes a silver electrode). OTOH, if  the zinc electrode is replaced by carbon one, there is no zinc to be oxidized to $\ce{Zn^2+}$ and the cell would not work, as $\ce{Zn^2+}$ cannot be oxidized either.

As any galvanic cell needs chemical processes providing electrons at their anodes and absorbing electrons at their cathodes. These processes may or may not chemically involve the material of the electrodes. Both inert electrodes can be used for electrolytes, that can be reduced at the cathode and oxidized at anode.

There is the commercial vanadium cell used for  energy storage, using 2 redox half-reactions below. The interesting fact is vanadium has there four different oxidation numbers, $\ce{V^{II}/V^{III}}$ in one of compartments and $\ce{V^{IV}/V^{V}}$ in the other:

Charging

\begin{align}
\ce{V^3+ + e-  &->V^2+}\\
\ce{VO^2+ + H2O &->  VO2^+ + e- + 2 H+ }\\
\end{align}

Discharging

\begin{align}
\ce{V^2+ &-> V^3+ + e-}\\
\ce{VO2^+ + e- + 2 H+  &-> VO^2+ + H2O  }
\end{align}